# Difference between optional and normal String

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

Difference between String?,String! and String

I am using this code :

```
    var myString:String? = nil
    var myString1:String = ""
    var myString2:String! = nil

    println(myString2)
```

Here it's giving nil in myString2 instead of run-time error.

Comment: Its optional, its either a String or its nil.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String? and String! (Two ways of creating an optional variable)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083842/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-two-ways-of-creating-an-opti)

Comment: Please tell me what is the difference in these three declarations given in the code above

Comment: please read _The Basics_ before you ask the difference between those three declarations in the code above: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 1):

There are better explanations out there, but the simple version is:

`String` is a String. It holds a String value.

`String?` is an Optional String. It can hold a String value or nil. You can unwrap the optional and immediately try to access the String value by using ! like this:

```
var str: String? = nil
str!.length
```

That code will result in a runtime error because str is nil. A safer way to get the value of the optional is to use an if let:

```
var str: String? = nil
if let myStr = str{
    myStr.length
}
```

That has the same functionality as the above code, but won't crash on nil values.

`String!` is an implicitly unwrapped optional. It works that same way as a regular optional but it is assumed to be non-nil, so when you call it it tries to access the value like it was a regular optional with ! after.

The reason `println` works on all these types is because it can take Strings, String Optionals, and nil values and handles them all.

```
var str: String? = "hello world"
println(str)
println(str!)
println(nil)
```

All should work.

Answer (score 0):

@connor's answer is correct.

```
var Amy:Wife? // Amy is your girlfriend, she may or may not be your wife.
var Amy:Wife  // Amy is your wife.
var Amy:Wife! // Amy will be your wife, no matter you like it or not.
```