# What's the differences between `!` & `?` operator in swift optional type?

Tags: swift

For example

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let number: Int
    init(number: Int) { self.number = number }
    var tenant: Person?
    deinit { print("Apartment #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var number73: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
number73 = Apartment(number: 73)

john?.apartment?.tenant?.name

john!.apartment = number73
number73!.tenant = john

//john?.apartment = number73
//number73?.tenant = john

john?.apartment?.tenant?.name
```

It seems `john?.apartment = number73` and `john!.apartment = number73` both work, and what's the difference of these two, in which case, which one is the preferred? Much thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String? and String! (Two ways of creating an optional variable)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083842/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-two-ways-of-creating-an-opti)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case `john?.apartment = number73`

- If `john` is `nil`, do nothing (same as send message to `nil` in Objective-C)
- If `john` is not `nil`, assign the number.

Case `john!.apartment = number73`

- If `john` is `nil`, raise a runtime error aka crash (the famous error: *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value*)
- If `john` is not `nil`, assign the number.

If it can be ensured that `john` is not `nil`, use the exclamation mark.
If `john` could be `nil`, use the question mark.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is that `?` will just return `nil` if any of the properties in the chain are `nil`. With `!`, the program will crash if one of the values is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put imagine ? as a closed box, it could have a value or have nothing (nil) inside it, an example to that:

```
let number: Int = 3
```

number is an integer value that is 3

```
let number: Int? = 3
```

number is a closed box that may contain an integer value 4

The ! is forcing the box (?) to give you a value, it used when you are 100% sure that there is value there otherwise it will crash.

The ! is also used to check if the box has a value or not like:

```
if number! = 3 {

  do stuff
}
```

Try not to use ! as much because there is a big chance that will give you crashes

Hope that help :)