# Swift what is the difference when unwrapping optional property using ? and?

Tags: swift, option-type

When read a Swift project I could not understand the following code:

```
self.myTabbar?.addSubview(button)
```

In my opinion ,It should looks like this:

```
self.myTabbar!.addSubview(button)
```

Why it is correct to use ?

Comment: Please have a look at the SWIFT documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between String? and String! (Two ways of creating an optional variable)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083842/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-two-ways-of-creating-an-opti)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an exclamation mark mean in the Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language)

Answer (score 1):

When you use ! you must be sure that the variable is not nil, otherwise it crashes. In this case is correct to use ? because the addSubview method call it's executed only if the variable is not nil, in case it is nil it just skips that line.