# Swift iOS Firebase -If the FirebaseAuth.FIRUser Object isn't nil how is it possible for the .email on it to return nil?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase's Email/Password Sign-In Method to create an account for a user. Using that method the user must have an email address to get authenticated into Firebase.

FirebaseAuth has a `FIRUser` object named `User`

[image]

When a user first creates an account or logs into an existing account in the callback the `User` object gets initialized:

Create Account:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
            (user, error) in

            // user's auth credentials are now created but user can still be nil
```

Logging into existing account:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
            (user, error) in

            // user's auth credentials are now accessed but user can still be nil
```

The `User` object has an `.email` Optional of type String on it that contain's the user's email address.

[image]

I use a singleton class to manage everything that happens through Firebase and in both situations above when the `User` objects gets initialized I pass that data through to my Firebase singleton's class properties. I know the User object can come back as nil so I run an `if-let` to make sure it isn't.

**My question is if using the Email/Password Sign-In Method if the `User` object isn't nil in the callback is it possible that the `.email` can be nil even though it's necessary to have it to make an account or log in?**

After I run the `if-let` statements I use `guard` statements to check and see if the `.email` isn't nil but it seems like it either can run before the the FirebaseSingleton properties gets initialized (which means it will be nil) or it might be unnecessary if the User object is guaranteed to return it with a value.

Btw in both situations wether the user is creating and account or logging in the emailTextFiled and passwordTextField will not be nil. I run whitespace, .isEmpty, and != nil checks on them.

My Code:

```
class FirebaseSingleton{

    static let sharedInstance = FirebaseSingleton()

    var dbRef: DatabaseReference? = Database.database().reference()
    var storageDbRef: StorageReference? = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://blablabla.appspot.com")
    var currentUser: User? = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var currentUserID: String? = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var currentUserEmail: String? = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    var currentUserPhotoUrl: URL? = Auth.auth().currentUser?.photoURL
    var currentUserDisplayName: String? = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
}
```

Creating an Account:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
                (user, error) in

                if error != nil { return }

                if let user = user{

                    let sharedInstance = FirebaseSingleton.sharedInstance
                    sharedInstance.currentUser = user
                    sharedInstance.currentUserID = user.uid
                    sharedInstance.currentUserEmail = user.email // at this point is it possible for this to be nil?
                    sharedInstance.currentUserPhotoUrl = user.photoURL
                    sharedInstance.currentUserDisplayName = user.displayName
                }else{
                   return
                }

                // is this guard statement necessary?
                guard let email = user.uid else { return }
})
```

Logging into an existing account:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
                (user, error) in

                if error != nil { return }

                if let user = user{

                    let sharedInstance = FirebaseSingleton.sharedInstance
                    sharedInstance.currentUser = user
                    sharedInstance.currentUserID = user.uid
                    sharedInstance.currentUserEmail = user.email // at this point is it possible for this to be nil?
                    sharedInstance.currentUserPhotoUrl = user.photoURL
                    sharedInstance.currentUserDisplayName = user.displayName
                }else{
                   return
                }

                // is this guard statements necessary?    
                guard let email = user.uid else { return }
})
```

Comment: as long as you check that your username and password text fields are both non empty strings when you are creating a user, .uid and .email should not be nil.

Comment: @kbunarjo hey thanks. I'll update my question to convert that but yes I'm 100% sure those fields won't be nil

Comment: Is Email/Password your only sign-in method? In particular do you have anonymous users enabled? Then you could have a user who hasn't logged in yet whose email is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a convo with @Benjamin Jimenez and per @kbunarjo suggestions I did some thinking and I realized that Firebase also has a Phone Sign-In Method. If it's enabled and a user chooses that as their sign-in method then the `.email` address would be nil because there wouldn't be an email address used to create an account.

[image]

For my situation since I'm using the Email/Password Sign-In Method then the `.email` should not be nil because it is the only way to create an account. But just as User can come back as nil in the completion handler (even with the correct email and password) maybe it’s possible that the email address can also come back as nil since it’s an Optional.

That being said the safest method to use would be another if-let to check to see if the `user.email` isn't nil and if for some strange reason that it is then use the email address that was entered into the emailTextField as an alternative. The email address entered into the emailTextField and password combo has to be correct otherwise the user won't get authenticated into Firebase and error != nil.

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: {
                (user, error) in

                // if the email address and/or password are incorrect then error != nil and the code below this wont run
                if error != nil { return }

                if let user = user{

                    let sharedInstance = FirebaseSingleton.sharedInstance
                    sharedInstance.currentUser = user
                    sharedInstance.currentUserID = user.uid
                    sharedInstance.currentUserPhotoUrl = user.photoURL
                    sharedInstance.currentUserDisplayName = user.displayName

                    // instead of the guard statement I use another ‘if-let’ if for some reason .email is nil
                    if let currentUserEmail = user.email {
                              sharedInstance.currentUserEmail = currentUserEmail
                         }else{
                              sharedInstance.currentUserEmail = self.emailTextField.text! // the email address entered into here has to be valid otherwise it would've never made it to this point
                    }
                }else{
                   return
                }
})
```

Use the same exact code for the callback if Creating an Account

As @rMickeyD noted the Facebook Sign-In Method won’t use the email address either. I’ve never used it so I didn’t include it. Basically if none of the other Sign-In Methods don’t use your email address then user.email will be nil. Even if though I have Anonymous Sign-In as an option the method to use Anonymous Sign-In doesn’t require an email address nor a password so it’s understood that email will be nil.

You should check the docs to see if they require the email or not for all the other Sign-In Methods but the Phone number doesn’t need it.

Comment: @Jake I forgot about the Phone Sign-In Method. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, Facebook sign in will not always have an email associated with it.

Comment: @rMickeyD thanks. I thought about adding all the other options but I never used any of them including the Facebook Method so I wasn’t sure. The only thing I was 100% sure about was the Phone not needing it. I’ll update the answer in a few to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what are you asking for (since to me looks more like a swift question than a firebase one), but as long as the user isn't nil, the `uid` property is not an optional (`String`) so user.uid will **never** be nil. it is not the same for the email which is an `String?` therefore **might** or not be `nil`

Comment: how's it not a Firebase question when the value I'm asking about is a value that is returned from Firebase? User.uid and User.email comes from FirebaseAuth

Comment: yes, but you are asking if those vars can or cannot be nil. `String` objects **cannot** be nil, swift does not allow that, otherwise the app would crash. `String?` objects can be nil, that are what optionals are for in Swift, It does not matter if it's a Firebase class or your own project class

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493241/swift-string-vs-string-vs-string

Comment: what your saying about optionals is true and yes you are correct a String can't be nil and an optional of type String? can be nil but my question isn't about a String or an optional of type String? my question is wether FirebaseAuth.User.email or uid can be nil. Ok fine uid can't be nil I'll admit I overlooked that but .email what I want to know is if the User object isn't nil but it it has an email address which is necessary to make an account (using email) how is it possible for .email to be nil

Comment: Ok, now we are discussing Firebase, and since `user.email` is an optional, I would rely on the things you are sure that aren't nil, `user.uid` and `emailTextField.text`. The email should not be different from the one in user.email otherwise the login wouldn't work

Comment: I updated the question and thanks for pointing out that the uid can't be nil