# ScrollTo in ScrollView not working as expected

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Basic scrollView . When using value for scrollView.scrollTo(value,anchor:.bottom) , it scrolls .
When replacing by its value "99" , it doesn t . NOt sure if this is intended or not .If not, would like to know how to use the value of the id instead of retrieving it frol the position of the element .

```
struct Testchat: View {
    @State private var listMessages: [MessageTest] = []
    @State private var scrolled = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(listMessages, id: \.id) { messageInList in
                        Text(messageInList.id)
                            .onAppear {
                                if !scrolled {
                                    let value = listMessages[99].id
                                    scrollView.scrollTo("99",anchor: .bottom)
                                    scrolled = true
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            for i in 0 ..< 100 {
                let messagetest:MessageTest = .init()
                messagetest.id = i.description
                messagetest.message = i.description
                listMessages.append(messagetest)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MessageTest: NSObject, Codable, ObservableObject {
    var message: String!
    var id: String!

    public override init() {
        message = "VOID"
        id = "VOID"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `.id(messageInList.id)` to your Text. But besides that, instead of using `String` as an id, `UUID` is better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . This is just a bare bone example of something more complex . IDs in my other case are firebaseIDs (very long) . I tried to add .id(id) to the view and it seems to work indeed .So i thank yo very much for your help .It is still quite weird that scroll works in one case and not the other (but this is not the first strange behaviour ...)

Comment: **Never ever** declare properties in a class or struct as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized in an `init` method. Don't. If you need optionals use regular optionals (`?`), otherwise non-optionals, the code complies even without the exclamation marks. SwiftUI encourages you much more than UIKit to  avoid optionals as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `ForEach`, your are identifying each row by the `\.id` key-path. The `id` property in `MessageTest` is an optional, of type `String!` (but is really a `String?` to mean `Optional<String>`).

Because of this, you need to pass in the row to scroll to as a `String?` type, rather than just `String`.

Change the line to the following, by adding the cast:

```
scrollView.scrollTo("99" as String?, anchor: .bottom)
```

Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37493313/9607863) to an answer about how `String?` and `String!` are both `Optional<String>`, but the `!` version is just implicitly force-unwrapped.

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer . Those "details" require an advanced knowledge of Ios . So the cast worked .Without casting as String? , adding the .id(id) to the view as indicated by aheze worked also .I guess this special case might help someone .Thank you

Comment: @it75 It's not really advanced knowledge of iOS, it's just how the SwiftUI framework works. Basically when working with `ScrollViewReader`, the type of the `id` of each view needs to be the same as the one you `scrollTo`. That's why we had to cast to a `String?`, so the type is the same. Setting an explicit `.id(...)` like that also worked because now you are just giving it a `String`, just like with `"99"` being a `String`.