# How to understand `!` and `?` in swift?

Tags: swift, syntax, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I'm new in swift.When i declare a variable,or when i get a property of an instance,I find "!" and "?" is everywhere.Doing such things in Objective-C is quite easy,you can even not know the type of class with the "id" type.Why do we need the `!` and the `?` ?

I want to know the reason of designing `!` and `?`,instead of how to use them.What's the advantage of having an optional type?

Comment: you should just google about `Optional` in swift, a lot of articles about it

Comment: I would suggest Apple Document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309.

var declare with '?' may or may not have any value. Declared var instance may be a 'nil' value. '!' mark used to ensure that declare var has non-nil value or it is initialized with a value. You can consider '!'  it as signal that you are owning the responsibility of the declared var with a non-nil value.

Comment: Read below answers ;-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083842/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-two-ways-of-creating-an-opti

Comment: To answer to your explicit Q: We do not need it. It is one of the concepts, people invented to make things saver, that are not dangerous and ended up in making things complicate, that has been quite simple. Well done.

Comment: the answer to the "why optionals?" question is [in documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/247/optionals/5984/overview-why-optionals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...

> **`? (Optional)`** indicates your variable may contain a nil value while **`! (unwrapper)`** indicates your variable must have a memory (or value) when it is used (tried to get a value from it) at runtime.

The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.

To reflect the fact that optional chaining can be called on a nil value, the result of an optional chaining call is always an optional value, even if the property, method, or subscript you are querying returns a nonoptional value. You can use this optional return value to check whether the optional chaining call was successful (the returned optional contains a value), or did not succeed due to a nil value in the chain (the returned optional value is nil).

Specifically, the result of an optional chaining call is of the same type as the expected return value, but wrapped in an optional. A property that normally returns an Int will return an *Int?* when accessed through optional chaining.

```
var defaultNil : Int?  // declared variable with default nil value
println(defaultNil) >> nil  

var canBeNil : Int? = 4
println(canBeNil) >> optional(4)

canBeNil = nil
println(canBeNil) >> nil

println(canBeNil!) >> // Here nil optional variable is being unwrapped using ! mark (symbol), that will show runtime error. Because a nil optional is being tried to get value using unwrapper

var canNotBeNil : Int! = 4
print(canNotBeNil) >> 4

var cantBeNil : Int = 4
cantBeNil = nil // can't do this as it's not optional and show a compile time error
```

[Here is basic tutorial in detail, by Apple Developer Committee.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: An implicitly unwrapped optional  *can* be nil ...

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) docs:

> You use optionals in situations where a value may be absent. **An
>   optional represents two possibilities: Either there is a value, and
>   you can unwrap the optional to access that value, or there isn’t a
>   value at all.**
>
> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The
>   nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a
>   method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the
>   absence of a valid object.”
>
> If you define an optional variable without providing a default value,
>   the variable is automatically set to nil for you:

```
var surveyAnswer: String?
```

> You can use an if statement to find out whether an optional contains a
>   value by comparing the optional against nil. You perform this
>   comparison with the “equal to” operator (==) or the “not equal to”
>   operator (!=).
>
> If an optional has a value, it is considered to be “not equal to” nil:

```
if convertedNumber != nil {
print("convertedNumber contains some integer value.") 
}
```

> Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can
>   access its underlying value by adding an **exclamation mark (!)** to the
>   end of the optional’s name. The exclamation mark effectively says, “**I
>   know that this optional definitely has a value**; please use it.” **This
>   is known as forced unwrapping of the optional’s value**:

```
print("convertedNumber has an integer value of \(convertedNumber!).")
```