# Force casts should be avoided

Tags: ios, swift, casting, option-type

I am getting "Force cast violation : Force casts should be avoided warning"
on my code :

```
daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0] as! [Any?]
```

The screenshot is attached below:

[image: The warning shown is in the image]

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "location", for: indexPath) as? TravelShopCustomCell {
        if !isFirstTime && self.nameArray.count != 0 {
            var daysCombined = [Any]()
            var daysCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            daysCombined = [self.combinedArray[0]]
            daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0] as? [Any?] ?? []
            let str = daysCombinedFinal.flatMap { $0 as? String }.joined(separator:" ")
            var startAMCombined = [Any]()
            var startAMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            startAMCombined = [self.combinedStartAMArray[0]]
            startAMCombinedFinal = startAMCombined[0] as? [Any?] ?? []
            var endPMCombined = [Any]()
            var endPMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            endPMCombined = [self.combinedEndPMArray[0]]
            endPMCombinedFinal = endPMCombined[0] as? [Any?] ?? []
            cell.operatingDaysLabel.text = str
            let isAMEqual = checkArrayStatus(testArray: [startAMCombinedFinal as Any])
            let isPMEqual = checkArrayStatus(testArray: [endPMCombinedFinal as Any])
            if isAMEqual && isPMEqual {
                self.mergedArray = arrayMerger(array1: startAMCombinedFinal, array2: endPMCombinedFinal)
            }
            let startTimeString = self.mergedArray[0] as? String
            let endTimeString = self.mergedArray[1] as? String
            cell.operatingTimeLabel.text = startTimeString! + " - " + endTimeString!
            return cell
        } else if isFirstTime && self.nameArray.count != 0 {
            var daysCombined = [Any]()
            var daysCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            daysCombined = [self.combinedArray[indexPath.row]]
            daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0] as! [Any?]
            let str = daysCombinedFinal.flatMap { $0 as? String }.joined(separator:" ")
            var startAMCombined = [Any]()
            var startAMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            startAMCombined = [self.combinedStartAMArray[indexPath.row]]
            startAMCombinedFinal = startAMCombined[0] as! [Any?]
            var endPMCombined = [Any]()
            var endPMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
            endPMCombined = [self.combinedEndPMArray[indexPath.row]]
            endPMCombinedFinal = endPMCombined[0] as! [Any?]
            cell.operatingDaysLabel.text = str
            let isAMEqual = checkArrayStatus(testArray: [startAMCombinedFinal as Any])
            let isPMEqual = checkArrayStatus(testArray: [endPMCombinedFinal as Any])
            if isAMEqual && isPMEqual {
                self.mergedArray = arrayMerger(array1: startAMCombinedFinal, array2: endPMCombinedFinal)
            }
            let startTimeString = self.mergedArray[0] as? String
            let endTimeString = self.mergedArray[1] as? String
            cell.operatingTimeLabel.text = startTimeString! + " - " + endTimeString!
            return cell
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        fatalError("Dequeueing SomeCell failed")
    }
}
```

The array declaration is:

```
var dateArray = [Any]()
var endAmTimeArray = [Any]()
var endPmTimeArray = [Any]()
var startAmTimeArray = [Any]()
var startPmTimeArray = [Any]()
var combinedArray = [Any]()
var combinedStartAMArray = [Any]()
var combinedEndPMArray = [Any]()
var mergedArray = [Any?]()
```

Comment: prefer using default values with '??' operator. e.g. daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0] as? [Any?] ?? []

Comment: assuming 'daysCombinedFinal' is an array

Comment: Do you really need arrays with optional items? That's the actual reason of the warning. And instead of most unspecified `Any` consider to use a more specific type.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `Any` anyway. Try to keep your arrays homogeneous.

Comment: @jrturton whatchoo talkin' bout? :P

Comment: @Fogmeister I never said nuffink

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has relation with concept of '**optional' & 'unwrapper**'. Here is brief about both and difference between them: [How to understand `!` and `?` in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994867/how-to-understand-and-in-swift/42994992#42994992)

> **? (Optional)** indicates your variable may contain a nil value while **! (unwrapper)** indicates your variable must have a memory (or value) when it is used (tried to get a value from it) at runtime.

In your case, you are trying to get value from array using index number. Now type of elements of your array is '**Any**'

So, there may be any kind of value/information contained by element of array. It will result into app crash, if you try to force unwrap a value of element, when it won't return a value or value with type that you're casting with unwrapper.

[Here is basic tutorial in detail, by Apple Developer Committee.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

This warning is indicating you, that your app may crash on force unwrapping optional value.

As a solution you should use **? (optional)** with **if-let** block, to avoid force unwrapping and safe execution of your code, like:

```
if let daysC = daysCombined[0] as? [Any] {
    daysCombinedFinal = daysC
}
```

Share your full source code, to get better solution of your query as you have not shared declaration of your array in your question. Because I've confusion about optional array [Any?] elements. Swift not allows array elements as optional.

**Update :** By considering elements of all arrays as 'Dictionary < String : Any >', forced unwraps from array assignments are removed here.

```
var daysCombined = [Any]()
var daysCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
daysCombined = [self.combinedArray[indexPath.row]]

// Update 1
// if combinedArray is an array of array
if let arrayElement = daysCombined[0] as? [Any] {
    daysCombinedFinal = arrayElement
}
let str = daysCombinedFinal.flatMap { $0 as? String }.joined(separator:" ")
var startAMCombined = [Any]()
var startAMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
startAMCombined = [self.combinedStartAMArray[indexPath.row]]

// Update 2
if let arrayElement = startAMCombined[0] as? [Any] {
    startAMCombinedFinal = arrayElement
}
var endPMCombined = [Any]()
var endPMCombinedFinal = [Any?]()
endPMCombined = [self.combinedEndPMArray[indexPath.row]]

// Update 3
if let arrayElement = endPMCombined[0] as? [Any] {
    endPMCombinedFinal = arrayElement
}

cell.operatingDaysLabel.text = str
```

Comment: The if-let is not required here. It could instead be done like this: daysCombinedFinal = daysCombined[0] as? [Any].

Comment: @RobertGummesson using `as? [Any]` still returns an optional. So you still have to unwrap it. Using `if let` would unwrap the optional so that `daysC` would not be.

Comment: Agree with @Fogmeister

Comment: True, if daysCombinedFinal is not an optional, if-let would be required. If not, you might as well put it on one line without the if-let.

Comment: @RobertGummesson Please suggest your concern by editing this answer

Comment: Yess it is a dictionary

Comment: combinedArray contains another array

Comment: still it is showing the warnings... what are the ambiguities?